# how to interact with an already deployed smart contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I was reading this [contract](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html#safe-remote-purchase) that I found in the solidity documentation and I assume this contract is unique and deployed by the auction house. All users can make an offer. From an implementation point of view, how does a user call the methods of this contract using web3.js if he didn't deploy it?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to deploy contract for calling its methods using web3.js.

Only if the methods need owner rights you could not be able to call its methods, but otherwise, you can call methods of the smart contract.

Also you can use Etherscan for calling contract methods. Navigate to the Contract section of your selected smart contract, then in sections `Read Contract` and `Write Contract` you can call contracts' methods.